# What is correct way of adding Custom Service in controller in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting error while adding custom service in angular js it's showing some dependency injection issue. Not able to figure it out how to fix it

**Not able to get solution for this please help**

**I have created app.js file**

```
var myModule = angular.module("myModule",["ngRoute"]);

myModule.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/", {
  template : "welcome"
})
.when("/add", {
  templateUrl : "/add/add.html",
  controller : "myController2"
});

}]);
```

**My service file it is named as myservice.js**

```
 myModule.factory('exportService', function(){

    return{

     downloadData  = function(){
         console.log("in download data methodd");
        $http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
      .then(function(response){
           $scope.data = response.data;
      }, function(error){
          console.log("error occured");
      });

    }
     }
   });
```

**My controller file**

```
myModule.controller('myController2',function($scope,exportService){

exportService.downloadData();

});
```

**my index.html file**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
<script src="./add/add.html"></script>
<script src="./add/add.js"></script>

 <script src="./add/myservice.js"></script> 
</head>

<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController2">
       <div>
          <input type="text" ng-model="message"/>
            {{message}}
        </div>
    </div> 
     <div ng-view></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

> I am getting error as Error: $injector:unpr
>      Unknown Provider
>      Unknown provider: exportServiceProvider <- exportService <- myController2

Comment: The service has a syntax error. Fix that and it should work better.

Comment: Be aware that `bootstrap.js` doesn't play will with `angular.js`.